# Derivatives with respect to Cartesian coordinates of functions in spherical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-transformation

This seems to me to be a common task, and the more surprised I was to not have found much on this.

Suppose I have an expression `f` in spherical coordinates `r,theta,phi`, and want to compute partial derivatives of `f` with respect to Cartesian coordinates `x,y,z`, but with the result expressed in `r,theta,phi` again.

I have solved it by defining the following function (in Mathematica 10):

```
myD[f_,n_Integer/;n>=1&&n<=3]:=
  With[{jac=Transpose@CoordinateTransformData["Spherical"->"Cartesian","InverseMappingJacobian",{r,theta,phi}]},
    jac[[n]].(D[f,#]&/@{r,theta,phi})
]
```

With this I can compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ by writing `myD[f,3]`. Take for example `f=r`, you should get:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=myD[f,3]=\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}=\frac{z}{r}=\frac{r\cos\theta}{r}=\cos\theta
$$

I was wondering if this is really the way to go for such a mundane task? I suspect that there is a nicer functionality built into Mathematica which I am not aware of. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You'll need at least a Coordinate Transform function. Yours isn't bad. Other ways of course exist: `f[r_] := r;
myD[f_, var_] := 
 FullSimplify[
  D[TransformedField[ "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
     f@r, {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]} -> {x, y, z}], var] /. 
   Thread[{x, y, z} -> 
     CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
      "Mapping", {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}]], Assumptions -> r > 0]`